# Generate random string and check into databse for non repetation

Tags: javascript, string, asp.net-mvc-3, random

In MVC-3 (Razor Engine) : I want to generate random string on a button click called `NextAvailable`, but condition is that before generation of random string look into SQL database that it is already generated or not. If already present in database, then generate a new string.
Can anybody please help me...
Here is my code for generating randon string:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function btnNextAvailable_OnClick() { 
     $("#nextAvailableButtonClick.val('true')"); 
     var mode = $.hash.getValue("m"); 
     var chars = "0123456789"; 
     var stringLength = 3; 
     var randomstring = ''; 
     for (var i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) { 
      var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length); 
      randomstring += chars.substring(rnum, rnum + 1); 
     } 
     document.getElementById("SequentialId").value = randomstring 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why not use Guids? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  function btnNextAvailable_OnClick() { 
        var randomstring=GenerateRandonString();
        while(IsRandomStringExists(randomstring))
        {
            document.getElementById("SequentialId").value = randomstring 
        }

        document.getElementById("SequentialId").value = randomstring 
    }
 function IsRandomStringExists(randomstring)
 {
   $.get('Home/CheckStringExists/'+randomstring  ,function(response)
     {

        if(response=="true")
            {
               return true;
            }else
           {
              return false;
           }
      });
   }
     function GenerateRandonString()
      {
        $("#nextAvailableButtonClick.val('true')"); 
        var mode = $.hash.getValue("m"); 
        var chars = "0123456789"; 
        var stringLength = 3; 
        var randomstring = ''; 
        for (var i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) { 
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length); 
        randomstring += chars.substring(rnum, rnum + 1); 
        return randomstring;
      }
```

Also create "CheckStringExists" ActionMethod in Home controller or in your controller with parameter.

In HomeController

```
public JsonResult CheckStringExists(string id)
{
    //Write database logic here
    return Json((object)"true", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In HomeController

```
public JsonResult CheckStringExists(string id)
{           
    var customer = ObjectContext.Companies.OfType<TrueTracEntities.Customer>().Where(r =>  r.SequentialId.Equals(id)).FirstOrDefault();      
    return Json((object)"true", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Hi Khalid, Thanks for your quick response. Can you please help me out how to code for ActionResult in my Home controller by passing parameters. I am very much new for MVC3.